# RegExp match a single quoted text without quotes - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, text, double-quotes

I'm sorry if it is a confusing question. I was trying to find a way to do this but couldn't find it so, if it is a repeated question, my apologies!

I have a text something like this: `something:"askjnqwe234"`

I want to be able to get `askjnqwe234` using a RegExp. You can notice I want to omit the quotes. I was trying this using `/[^"]+(?=(" ")|"$)/g` but it returns an array. I want a RegExt to return a single string, not an array.

I don't know if it's possible but I do not want to specify the position of the array; something like this:

`var x = string.match(/[^"]+(?=(" ")|"$)/g)[0];`

Thanks!

Comment: The JavaScript regex matching functions always return either an array or `null` (except `.test()` which returns just a boolean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` and `exec` always return an array or `null`, so, assuming you have a single double-quoted value and no newlines in the string, you could use

```
var x;
var str = 'something:"askjnqwe234"';

x = str.replace( /^[^"]*"|".*/g, '' );
// "askjnqwe234"
```

Or, if you may have other quoted values in the string

```
x = str.replace( /.*?something:"([^"]*)".*/, '$1' );
```

where `$1` refers to the substring captured by the sub-pattern `[^"]*` between the `()`.

Further explanation on request.

Notwithstanding the above, I recommend that you tolerate the array indexing and just use `match`.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
/"([^"]*)"/g
```

in English: look for `"` the match and record anything that isn't `"` till you see another `"`".

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the information inside quotes like this, assuming it matches:

```
var x = string.match(/something:"([^"]*)"/)[1];
```

The memory capture at index 1 is the part inside the double quotes.

If you're not sure it will match:

```
var match = string.match(/something:"([^"]*)"/);

if (match) {
    // use match[1] here
}
```